# Mac OS Blocks Reinstall on Macbook Pro 2019

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

My work donated a Macbook Pro to me, when I attempt to reinstall a clean copy of Mac OS Catalina via USB drive I receive a message saying that I don't have permission to install Mac OS.  Anyway to get around this?

Comment: please give more details and/or screenshots, etc. Did you make a USB installer drive, and that's where you are getting the error?

Comment: Are you trying to install on the USB stick itself? Have you tried formatting the drive from the recovery console first - you may need to go to the device in Disk Utility (drop down menu lefthand side - show all devices).  NOTE this can leave you with no way to make another USB stick so you could be forced to use internet recovery if your boot version supports it.

Comment: @Andyroo - No, i'm trying to install to the hard drive of the macbook.  The installation media is a USB stick. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @MatthewBarclay - Yes, I made a USB stick with the Mac OS installer on it.  I'm trying to use that to install a fresh copy of Mac OS on the macbook pro HDD....

Comment: Try the same as above but select the internal drive device.